# JMeter - Summary Report from non gui mode

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have some web services to test on Jmeter. I added a listener Summary Report and using JMeter in NON-GUI mode. Here is the file I am getting after configuring the summary report through JMeter.

[image]

Here you can see "Check for Update" is written 5 times, that means thread count was 5. I want to group these 5 entries just like in actual summary report and all the other values should be average of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Summary Report listener` to get each HTTP sampler execution value per grouped by the HTTP Sampler name.

Comment: I am asking about non-gui mode

Comment: Try this:
java -jar JMeterPluginsCMD.jar --generate-csv aggregateResults.csv --input-jtl testResults.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve your desired output:

1. Launch the JMeter application (GUI Mode) and open the script you used (.jmx file) in non-gui mode.
2. Add Summary Report Listener, if not present.
   [image]
3. Load the summary report file using the browse button.
   [image]

If you want to include the median and the 90th percentile in your report, you can use the Aggregate Report Listener.